# Difference between texture arrays and multiple single textures?

Tags: textures, directx11, directx10

I've just learnt that DirectX 10 and above have a feature called "texture arrays". Which, basically, is just a normal array of textures (shader resources) which in a shader is declared like:

```
Texture2D myTextures[2];
```

What I've been using so far is 2 multiple separate textures:

```
Texture2D myFirstTexture;
Texture2D mySecondTexture;
```

Is there any practical (performance, memory etc...) difference between the two?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not exactly: texture arrays are declared in HLSL as `Texture2DArray` for Texture2D and not as an array of texture, so it is quite different. They are almost acting as a 3D texture, where the z is a slice of the 2D Texture (in terms of uv, it is the w dimension). The difference with 3D texture is that they are not supporting trilinear interpolation between the 2D slices but you can still select dynamically a Texture2D slice with a z/w component (unlike an array of texture), the z/w component is rounded to the nearest integer to select the z/w slice. Concerning the memory, I believe this is equivalent, for performance, not sure they give a huge boost even accessing a set of Texture2D compare to an array of texture (but they support dynamic indexing). Using `Texture2DArray` is also easier as you only need to bind it to a single slot.

Comment: Oh, I was following this tutorial: http://www.rastertek.com/dx11tut17.html and it uses an array of textures. Is it incorrect then (in calling it a texture array)?

Comment: "but this should be better" But **what** should be better?

Comment: Sorry for stacking comments but these are separate issues. I've just found this thread: http://www.gamedev.net/topic/626359-technical-differences-between-texture1darray-and-texture2d/ Is it wrong? Do `TextureXDArray`s support interpolating between slices?

Comment: For the last one - I haven't tried but I believe I **should** be able to.

Comment: @NPS I did verify and arrays of texture cannot be indexed dynamically (which make sense and the reason why Texture2DArray were introduced). I have updated my answer.

Comment: No, trilinear interpolation isn't done with `Texture2DArray`, only with volume textures (`Texture3D`).  The z component of the texture coordinate simply selects a slice using its integer index; no blending between slices is done.  That gamedev.net topic you linked to is correct.

Comment: @NathanReed Oops, just checked this and you are absolutely right. I have updated my answer to reflect this. Sorry for giving false direction.